# are there any methods like save in mongoose to remove a record?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

i liked the method save a lot, if i want to update something, I can simply find it and edit and save it. But how can i remove something using such a method. is there any remove method in mongoose?

Comment: Have you tried anything before asking a question over here?

Comment: Just search google for "mongoose remove", this is a very broad question.